# Magesolution Product Video

Tags: product, video

Our company have installed the Magesolution Product Video extension but it only works in the frontend when the site is set to default theme. When a different theme is set, the extension does not show on the frontend, what would you recommend that I do so that the extension works even on the non-default theme? Thanks!

Comment: Add the same .phtml file & .xml files from default theme to your non-default theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a product video without using an extension. You can do so by editing some files programmatically as explained below.

Create “video” text input attribute. Add it to appropriate attribute set and reindex your data.

Go to the following file.

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Find the following code in the above file.

```
<div class="product-name">
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

Insert the following code to add the video under the product name.

```
<?php if($_product->getVideo()): ?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getVideo() ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

download your extension and check if extension layout and phtml files were in the `rwd/default` folder or in the `default/default` folder,

if its in `default/default` folder than copy into your `Yourpackage/Yourtheme` folder and do same as for skin folder to .
Hope this will help you